# Libre Office 5.1.6.2 broken on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 32-bit

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

Just crashes with no explanation. Running from the command line

`loffice -o ./Documents/example.odt`

it pops a window with header: LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 and the box contains two lines

General Error

General input/output error.

I figure it got broken in one of the updates. Any suggestions on pinpointing the error?

Comment: Have you tried other ODT document (for example [Official LibreOffice 5.2 Getting Started guide](http://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.1/GS51-GettingStartedLO.odt) )?

Comment: The user LibreOffice user user profile files were corrupt.  Went and renamed directory .config/libreoffice say to .config/libreoffice-OLD and then everything works.  Libre Office creates a new .config/libreoffice and everything works.   IT NOW WORKS.